# Vibe.D - undefinded identifier (Dlang)

Tags: d, vibed

I'm trying to create simple REST api, but when i try to compile my code im getting

> frontpage.d(15,3): Error: undefined identifier 'tmp', did you mean
>   alias 'cmp'?

Here is my code:

```
module service.frontpage;

import vibe.d;

@path("/api")
interface IFrontPageAPI
{
  Json getHome();
}

class FrontPageAPI : IFrontPageAPI
{


  this(auto tmp) 
  {
    auto collect = tmp;
  }

  Json getHome()
  {
    logInfo("Getting HomePage from DB");  
    Bson query = Bson(["_id" : Bson("homepage")]);
    auto result = collect.find(query);


    logInfo("Iterating results...");
    foreach (i, doc; result.byPair)
    logInfo("Item %d: %s", i, doc.toJson().toString());

    return result.toJson();
  }
}
```

Can someone help me with it? tmp is temporary variable to pass mongoDB collection handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same answer as on [DLearn](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/rmzvlyrmjwizffoeafku@forum.dlang.org).

You need to
- use Class variables
- use types instead auto (here Mongo collection)
- return a proper Json

Have a look at [this interactive example](https://run.dlang.io/?compiler=dmd&source=%2F%2Bdub.sdl:%0Aname%20"foo"%0Adependency%20"vibe-d"%20version%3D"~>0.8.0"%0A%2B%2F%20%2F**%2F%0Aimport%20vibe.d;%0Aimport%20std.algorithm,%20std.array;%0A%0A@path("%2Fapi")%0Ainterface%20IFrontPageAPI%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Json%20getHome();%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20FrontPageAPI%20:%20IFrontPageAPI%0A%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20MongoCollection%20collect;%0A%0A%20%20%20%20this(MongoCollection%20tmp)%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20collect%20%3D%20tmp;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Json%20getHome()%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20logInfo("Getting%20HomePage%20from%20DB");%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Bson%20query%20%3D%20Bson(%5B"_id"%20:%20Bson("homepage")%5D);%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20auto%20result%20%3D%20collect.find(query);%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20logInfo("Iterating%20results...");%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foreach%20(i,%20doc;%20result.byPair)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20logInfo("Item%20%25d:%20%25s",%20i,%20doc.toJson().toString());%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Json(result.map!(a%20%3D>%20a.toJson).array);%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid%20main()%0A%7B%0A%7D) - and feel free to play with it. No output means no compilation error.

Comment: Thank you it solves my problem but right now im getting another error (described under DLearn link which you attached)